# How can I count the length of string in RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, validation, passwords

Here is my pattern:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$
```

It's a password validation. As you know:

`^` Matches the start of the string

`(?=.*[a-z])` checks if somewhere in the string is a lowercase character

`(?=.*[A-Z])` checks if somewhere in the string is a uppercase character

---

Now I need to add some *count conditions* to the pattern. I mean, I need to count:

1. The length of whole string should be more than 6 characters. *(I guess I should use something like this `{6,}`, but I don't know how should I use it)*
2. The number of capital characters should be at least three ones. *(this condition isn't very important, if implementing that is hard, I can ignore it)*

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantifiers are key here. You can use `{6,}` for your matching pattern for the first conditions and expand your second lookahead a bit for your second condition, like

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3}).{6,}$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/DjSqbr/1

Note: I have extended `[^A-Z]` to `[^A-Z\r\n]` to work properly with multline strings.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=(.*[A-Z]){3,}).{6,}$
```

You can check [here](http://regexr.com/3g9ab)